# Custom Wordpress Admin PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, glob

I am trying to load images from a specific directory to load into the admin settings page for my current theme.

```
<?php 
$dirname = "panos/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
$imageNameLong = substr($image, -14);
$imageName = substr($imageNameLong,0 , -4);

echo '
<img id="'.$imageName.'" src="resize.php?w=450&amp;img='.$image.'" >
' }?>
```

This was working on my last site which wasnt within wordpress. I used a different method but then backtracked because this is the optimal code for this situation. I am trying to get all .jpg files within the panos folder which is in the correct location and then use my resize.php script as well, but the first problem is i cannot get it to recognize the files in the folder! PLEASE HELP!

Comment: are you sure glob is available on your server? Wouldn't it be better to provide the actual path instead of having it map out any found instance of panos/? If you have many panos directories it might be a good idea to rethink your structure. Just my opinion

Comment: I agree completely but for initial testing purposes this should work with the one panos folder i have. the problem is that it returns nothing as if the folder is empty.

Comment: I'm not going to lie I'm a bit of a PHP noob. if i chance the $dirname to an actual path do I just put `$dirname = "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/Explorable/panos";` ?

Comment: no, for internal use you would use the server path: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path-to-folder/'` where path to folder is relative to web root. try doing something like print_r($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) first to see what path that returns for you. It may resolve a lot of your questions just seeing the path this way.

Comment: YES! That did the trick! thanks a million! Now it seems my resize.php is not doing what it was on my other site. I'm not sure if you would be able to help me with figuring that out [Here is the code from resize.php](http://kl1p.com/WxXv) when i used to go to the php file on my old server it would say "error division by zero" because there was no input file and now when i go to it its just a blank page which leads me to believe something is going wrong.

Comment: Or since I'm using wordpress now is there some php resize code that i could use to resize them each to a specific width?

Comment: I may be able to. I converted that last comment to an answer so you can accept. You should post the image problem as a separate question though since it doesn't relate to this original question.

Comment: i actually did! [Here is the link to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800354/php-resize-script-not-working-on-new-server-domain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to an actual path instead of using `glob()` to find all that match. It is architecturally more sane to use server paths if you only have one panos directory.

For internal use you would use the server path:

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path-to-folder/'`

where path to folder is relative to web root. try doing something like `print_r($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` first to see what path that returns for you. It may resolve a lot of your questions just seeing the path this way.