# PHP Resize Script not working on new server/domain

Tags: php, wordpress, image-resizing

I had the resize.php script working on my previous server/domain and when you go to it [HERE](http://go3dexpansion.com/temp/public_html/generatesim/resize.php) you can see the division by zero error. BUT! if you go to the same script on the new domain/server [HERE](http://go3de.com/wp-admin/resize.php)its a blank page with no errors which leads me to believe something is not happening like it should be. I'm a quick learner but a bit of a PHP noob. Any advice with simply resizing a php array of images and displaying them I would appreciate any help.

```
<?php session_start();header("Pragma: public");header("Cache-Control: max-age = 604800");
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 604800)." GMT");

function thumbnail($image, $width, $height) {

    if($image[0] != "/") { // Decide where to look for the image if a full path is not given
        if(!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) { // Try to find image if accessed directly from this script in a browser
            $image = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].implode("/", (explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], -1)))."/".$image;
        } else {
            $image = implode("/", (explode('/', $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], -1)))."/".$image;
        }
    } else {
        $image = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$image;
    }
    $image_properties = getimagesize($image);
    $image_width = $image_properties[0];
    $image_height = $image_properties[1];
    $image_ratio = $image_width / $image_height;
    $type = $image_properties["mime"];

    if(!$width && !$height) {
        $width = $image_width;
        $height = $image_height;
    }
    if(!$width) {
        $width = round($height * $image_ratio);
    }
    if(!$height) {
        $height = round($width / $image_ratio);
    }

    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    } elseif($type == "image/png") {
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $thumb = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $temp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($temp_image, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);
    $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $temp_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        imagejpeg($thumbnail);
    } else {
        imagepng($thumbnail);
    }

    imagedestroy($temp_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail);

}

if(isset($_GET["h"])) { $h = $_GET["h"]; } else { $h = 0; }
if(isset($_GET["w"])) { $w = $_GET["w"]; } else { $w = 0; }

thumbnail($_GET["img"], $w, $h);

?>
```

Comment: I would make sure errors are turned on for debugging, check if the GD library is enabled using phpinfo(), and make sure that the directory where the thumbs are created is writable.

Comment: AH! nearly all of that went right over my head. GD library? Im so sorry haha I said i was a noob!

Comment: guess thats it. i dont see the gd library at all in the info log. How would i go about install that?

Comment: Found out how to install it. Please post your comment as an answer so that i can approve it! :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure errors are turned on for debugging, check if the GD library is enabled using phpinfo(), and make sure that the directory where the thumbs are created is writable.

Comment: Installed the GD Library and still having some issues. I posted another question if you want to go there i would love some help on fixing this! [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817599/php-script-not-working-gd-library-installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817599/php-script-not-working-gd-library-installed)

Comment: Now where I believe it should be working [HERE](http://go3de.com/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php?w=450&img=panos/Pano__0001.jpg) i get this error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php:1) in /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php on line 35 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php on line 36`