# PHP script not working GD Library installed

Tags: php, gd, image-resizing

Below is my resize.php script. I needed to install the GD Library and did so but I am still having trouble gettint the image to process like it used to my old server.[HERE](http://go3de.com/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php?w=450&img=../wp-content/themes/Explorable/panos/Pano__0000.jpg) You can see with the error reporting on there is an empty image created and the following errors display:

> `Warning:
>   getimagesize(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817599/../wp-content/themes/Explorable/panos/Pano__0000.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  in
>   /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php on
>   line 16`
>
> `Warning: Division by zero in
>   /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php on
>   line 19`
>
> `Warning: Division by zero in
>   /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php on
>   line 30`

What is going wrong? PLEASE HELP!

```
<?php session_start();header("Pragma: public");header("Cache-Control: max-age = 604800");
header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 604800)." GMT");

function thumbnail($image, $width, $height) {

    if($image[0] != "/") { // Decide where to look for the image if a full path is not given
        if(!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) { // Try to find image if accessed directly from this script in a browser
            $image = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].implode("/", (explode('/', $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], -1)))."/".$image;
        } else {
            $image = implode("/", (explode('/', $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], -1)))."/".$image;
        }
    } else {
        $image = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$image;
    }
    $image_properties = getimagesize($image);
    $image_width = $image_properties[0];
    $image_height = $image_properties[1];
    $image_ratio = $image_width / $image_height;
    $type = $image_properties["mime"];

    if(!$width && !$height) {
        $width = $image_width;
        $height = $image_height;
    }
    if(!$width) {
        $width = round($height * $image_ratio);
    }
    if(!$height) {
        $height = round($width / $image_ratio);
    }

    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    } elseif($type == "image/png") {
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        $thumb = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    $temp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($temp_image, $thumb, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image_width, $image_height);
    $thumbnail = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($thumbnail, $temp_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);

    if($type == "image/jpeg") {
        imagejpeg($thumbnail);
    } else {
        imagepng($thumbnail);
    }

    imagedestroy($temp_image);
    imagedestroy($thumbnail);

}

if(isset($_GET["h"])) { $h = $_GET["h"]; } else { $h = 0; }
if(isset($_GET["w"])) { $w = $_GET["w"]; } else { $w = 0; }

thumbnail($_GET["img"], $w, $h);

?>
```

Comment: Is url fopen wrappers enabled? ([allow_url_fopen](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen))

Comment: If you have an empty image, this is probably because an error is returned. Remove the header and you will see what error you get.

Comment: url fopen is enabled. someone please help i have no clue what is going wrong

Comment: Now where I believe it should be working [HERE](http://go3de.com/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php?w=450&img=panos/Pano__0001.jpg) i get this error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php:1) in /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php on line 35 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/go3de/public_html/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php on line 36`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! I had a space before the initial `<?php` opening tag which caused the error! AH! sorry for being a noob!

Comment: Yep. Anything outputted before header() will cause it to not work (including a space) :-)

Answer (score 1):

How big is the image you're trying to resize? Looks like it's complaining about running out of memory?

Try allocating more memory.

You can try adding this at the very top of the page:
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
...and see if it works.

Comment: that seems to have done something but now i just some garbled output. still no image [see link here](http://go3de.com/wp-content/themes/Explorable/resize.php?w=450&img=panos/Pano__0001.jpg)

Comment: That's fine, it's probably because it can't set the headers right because of warnings. Try turning errors off and see if it works. Also, make sure it's a jpg or png (i.g. gifs don't seem to be supported in the script). Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Still just getting the same thing but without the errors. And they are all jpg files! Any other ideas?